# Installing app from google play in my SD Card

Tags: internal-storage

I like hearing to songs through [tuneQ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hiddenbrains) app (Scosche), which I had downloaded from Google Play. tuneQ is a music player.

Unfortunately the player lists songs present in my Internal Memory. I want to install the tuneQ player in my SD card so that I can have access to all the songs in my SD card.

Comment: I hope I've picked the correct app to link from Google Play -- but there was only one by that name. So I'm sorry to inform you, but that's *not* a "music player": *tuneQ is a graphic equalizer app* -- so it's for adjusting your sound quality. But even if: you don't need to install an app to your SDCard in order to enable it reading there. Would you please check what music player you are really using, and [update your question](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46004/edit) accordingly? Songs on your card should be automatically found. Make sure there's no `.nomedia` file in their folders.

Comment: Hi, tuneQ is a graphic equalizer as well as a music player.I have a couple of songs in my internal memory, But i dont see my songs present in my memory card listed in my tuneq player.About .nomedia can you tell where the folder is located? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would be very much thankful if you can suggest me a very professional music player with equalizer settings of high quality that is free, which i can download from google play.I would very much appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Please not that questions on app recommendations are off topic here (see our [FAQ] for details). As for the `.nomedia` file: it's a *file* which tells the MediaScanner to skip the directory it is located in. So you need to check the directories on your SDCard (where you say your music files are located) whether there's such a file present. You can use a file explorer for this, or check the card on your computer. Hint: files starting with a dot (like `.nomedia`) are hidden by default, so you need to configure your file browser to display hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Apollo Music Player"-app by the CyanogenMod team? As far as I know you cannot read and play music from the external memory if the application is not able to. So you won't fix it by installing the app on the external SDcard.

The Appolo Music Player is:

- Free
- Great
- Equalizer
- High Quality

This cannot be downloaded from the Google Market, but you might grab it from XDA (just be sure to enable to permit installing from unknown sources):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2196385